# Get Permalink of Network Blog Post

Tags: multisite, blog-id, permalinks

I am trying to write a function that will allow me to specify a post ID and a blog ID, and then have it return the permalink and title of the blog post.

I need this to be efficient because the function will be used in a foreach loop that could cause the function to run upwards of 50 times.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use some form of caching ( with Transients for instance http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache the results in between? I'd suggest to first write the function before dealing with performance. See also: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea on the performance issues caused by using switch_to_blog() ?

Comment: Hey @Pippin, did you ever get this sorted out? If so, it would be great to post your answer/findings here for others. Thanks!

Comment: No, a solution was never found.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds pretty simple.

Use: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog

To go back use:

```
restore_current_blog();
```

This allows you to switch from site to site.

Then: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

My assumptions are that you have both the Blog ID and the Post ID.

If that's the case - using those two functions should solve your problem.

Comment: `switch_to_blog()` documentation states that this function is a performance hog and should not be used in frontend functions.

Comment: I'm not seeing that for what it's worth.

Comment: I meant "_This switch is to be used for internal and admin area functions. It's too expensive a query to run on the front end._" part on https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog. I could be misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Ah yes. You're correct. It might be an option to attache this work to a cron -- have it generate a cached list of all the blog sensitive related data you needed. That's a little lame hack though.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion above, I've gone for this:

```
$html = '<ul>';
foreach ( $recent_across_network as $post ) {

    switch_to_blog( $post->blog_id );

    $postURI = get_permalink( $post->ID );          
    $html .= '<li><a href="' . $postURI . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></li>';

    restore_current_blog();
}
$html .= '</ul>';
```

where `$recent_across_network` is a list of recent posts from across a multisite network, cached using the Transients API. There's a [related tutorial here](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/17/wordpress-multisite-practical-functions-methods/).

You could equally do:

```
$postURI = get_blog_permalink( $post->blog_id, $post->ID );
```

instead of `switch_to_blog()` / `restore_current_blog()` - not sure which is more efficient?